# Benefits of the stack-based Finite State Machine implementation

Tags: c++, design-patterns, stack, game-engine, fsm

I'm developing a 2D game for my final course assignment (term paper), showing the best techniques of the game development, design patterns, different algorithms and more.

I haver never developed a game before and I'm struggling very hard to design a game engine that involves the best practices of the design patterns.

For the game state management (intro, menu, loading, playing...), I decided to use a FSM. There's a [state design pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html) and finite state machines using stacks. Are there any benefits using one or another? What is the mostly used approach?

Comment: May be you'd like [this one](https://github.com/makulik/sttcl).

Answer (score 0):

> I decided to use a FSM. There's a state design pattern and finite state machines using stacks. Are there any benefits using one or another?

I can't see a clear differentiation made from your question.

> What is the mostly used approach?

That cannot really be answered here, you'll rather need to put a statistical survey. And such is off-topic here, sorry.

---

The [*State Pattern*](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state/cpp/1) is well known since introduced from the GoF classic patterns.

The problem is though, that the raw state pattern doesn't map well to the classical Harel state machine diagrams that were adopted by the UML standard.

I've created a [template library](https://github.com/makulik/sttcl) that covers this gap, with the goal to have as little overhead as possible.

---

There are of course other approaches like [Boost Meta State Machine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0_b1/libs/msm/doc/HTML/ch02s02.html), or the [Boost Statechart Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/statechart/doc/index.html), and certainly others.

I hope you like my approach.

Comment: Basically, I just want to know when stack-based FSM should be used, if nowadays theyre used at all, and now, why is your templated FSM 'better' than others (why did you make it templated?). The states I'm trying to manage are Intro, Menu, Loading, Playing and Paused, for example.

Comment: @YvesHenri You probably should elaborate more about what you mean with a _stack based state machine_, May be I'm not getting well what you're actually after.

Answer (score 0):

> There's a state design pattern and finite state machines using stacks.

Simple finite state machine doesn't need stack to operate because it doesn't have memory. In other words, it doesn't need to know about past states. So if you need finite state machine you only need one pointer (or integer) to record "current" state...that's all.

But sometimes it's convenient to remember the state where it was. For example, if you're making menu which has hierarchy it needs to track which menu was opened before (to implement "back" button or something). So in this case, it's useful to remember past states by keeping them on the stack. Or you can implement some sort of interruption mechanism for your NPC by keeping track of state history.

By the way, state machine using stack is called pushdown automation. it's different from finite state machine on theory and practice. But well, we're game programmer so use whatever convenient for your application.

After all, You can use "state design pattern" for both of them because it's just a technique of software design. If you want to use FSM with stack you can use state design pattern and a stack which stores the pointer to the (instance of) state classes. Simple as that.

By the way, "design pattern" and "computational model (like state machine)" is fundamentally different...so comparing these two things is actually invalid, I think. Design patterns are just a coding pattern while computational model is more universal concept.

So there's no answer for your question.